# Fragment not added in framelayout in loop

Tags: android, android-fragments

Created class which extends `CardView` class. I am passing `FragmentManager` as parameter in constructor to add `Fragment` in `FrameLayout`. `Fragment` is added in `FrameLayout` but if I keep on calling custom created class in loop then `Fragments` are not getting added in `FrameLayout` instead content of 1st `FrameLayout` is getting replaced.

Code to add `Fragment` in `FrameLayout`:

```
mFragmentManager.beginTransaction().add(R.id.card_content, this.detailFragment).commitNow();
```

Comment: As I understood, the code is supposed to do eactly what you asked it to do - add the fragment's content on top of FrameLayout's content. What I don't understand is what you want it to do. Can you clarify?

Comment: I want it to add new fragment on top of FrameLayout's content in loop.

Comment: ok, then I don't understand what is the problem. the code should do it (if you did the loop correctly). So what it does instead?

Comment: `FragmentManager` is going to use the first `ViewGroup` with ID `card_content` it finds in the whole hierarchy. Passing it to your custom `CardView` isn't going to restrict it to just whatever is inside that `CardView`. After the first `CardView` is added, its `card_content` is what's going you be used for each transaction. Your design seems a little inverted. Why isn't the `CardView` in the `Fragment`'s layout?

Comment: thanks @MikeM. for explanation :)